# ExternalInterface not working in IE

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, externalinterface

I am trying to call an action in a flash object from the javascript:

as:

```
function testExternalConnection(str:String):Void {
    _root.debug.htmlText = "testExternalConnection ok";
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("testExternalConnection", this, testExternalConnection);
```

js:

```
var movie = getFlashMovie("ap1_mod_hidden")
movie.testExternalConnection();
```

with

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}
```

I'm including my flash using swfobject:

```
<span id="ap1_mod_hidden"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Setting up the flash player
    var flashvars = {
        mp3Path: "stop",
        artistName : "",
        trackName : ""
    };
    var params = {
        codebase: 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
        src: '/flash/ap1_mod.swf',
        quality: 'high',
        pluginspage: 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
        scale: 'showall',
        devicefont: 'false',
        bgcolor: '#999999',
        name: 'ap1_mod',
        menu: 'true',
        id: 'mod',
        allowFullScreen: 'false',
        allowScriptAccess:'always', //sameDomain
        movie: '/flash/ap1_mod.swf',
    wmode: "transparent",
    allowfullscreen: "true"
    };

    swfobject.embedSWF("/flash/ap1_mod.swf", "ap1_mod_hidden", "300", "300", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params);
</script>
```

Nothing crazy here. So this code is working fine in everything but not in Internet Explorer (what a surprise :\ ). It is getting the movie object correctly but it is not able to call the externalinterface function. It's saying that the property is not defined.

I've looked on google and SO with no success... any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps IE is cranky because you're not supplying the str argument to testExternalConnection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want to use the id, not the div you're adding the swf too so:

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
    return swfobject.getObjectById("mod");
}
```

since you're setting "mod" as the id.

Comment: swfobject.embedSWF does not actually insert the swf into the specified element, but instead replaces the element.  Kind of weird!

Comment: glad to help! swfobject 2.0's  new div replacing thing totally confused me the first time I tried to set up externalinterface too, the old version just replaced the innerHTML, so it was kinda unexpected.

Comment: yes, I was expecting it to change the innerHtml... Well thanks again :)