# IE not letting flash stream audio

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3, internet-explorer, swfobject

This problem is happening is both IE8 and IE7. I have a small swf  compiled with flex. It's basically just a wrapper around audio streaming functionality. All the controls and such are in html with javascript. I load the swf using swfobject's "static" method. This works great in Firefox and Chrome. In IE, the swf loads correctly, but as soon as I try to stream any audio with it, I get an error.

*EDIT:* I've reduced the code quite a bit to try and find the problem. You can see the new version running [here](http://defrex.com/IE_streaming_test/flash_isolation_test.html). Here is the error, html and flex files for my reduced version:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at isolated/playStream()[/home/defrex/code/bd/trunk/ackbar/media/flex/isolated.mxml:19]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_callIn()
    at <anonymous>()
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>fuie</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script>
            var player;
            swfobject.registerObject("_mediaplayer", "9.0.0", undefined, function(e){
                if (e.success)
                    player = e.ref;
                else
                    console.log('Flash not loaded');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="player.play_fuie('celebration.mp3');return false;">play track</a>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="1" height="1" id="_mediaplayer">
            <param name="movie" value="isolated.swf" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="isolated.swf" width="1" height="1">
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the flex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
        import flash.media.Sound;
        import flash.media.SoundChannel;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;

        public function init():void {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("play_fuie", playStream);
            ExternalInterface.call("console.log('flash loaded')");
        }

        public function playStream(stream:String):void {
            var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(stream);
            var audio:Sound = new Sound();
            audio.load(url);
            var chan:SoundChannel = audio.play();
            chan.soundTransform.volume = 0.5;
        }
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 frustrating days if debugging, the moral of the story: software piracy is bad. As it turns out the sketchy "XP Pirate Edition" that was passed around the dev team for IE testing in VirtualBox had some kind of bug (or perhaps malware) that was causing the issue. When we tried the test in Chrome installed in the same VM and it came up with the same error (while Chromium under Linux was working beautifully), we realized that there might be something wrong with the OS. Sure enough, when we got our hands on a legitimate version of IE everything worked perfectly.

Karma can be cruel.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to see in your code how stream is passed to flash , if it is from your flash params keep in mind that ie and firefox have different syntax to passing parameters to flash object

http://www.cflex.net/showFileDetails.cfm?ChannelID=1&Object=File&ObjectID=285

Comment: I've edited the question to show this, but the function is called via ExternalInterface. It's passed in as a string from JavaScript.

Comment: I just run into this ( with some surpeise since i also use external interfaces that should run on mac ).
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html
Use the ExternalInterface class in the following combinations of browser and operating system:

Browser Operating System Operating System 
Internet Explorer 5.0 and later  Windows    
Netscape 8.0 and later  Windows   MacOS  
Mozilla 1.7.5 and later  Windows   MacOS  
Firefox 1.0 and later  Windows   MacOS  
Safari 1.3 and later    MacOS  

so if you are running on mac might be an issue .

Comment: mabe this will help :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166079/externalinterface-not-working-in-ie

Comment: Eran, this all works great on macs, and I'm using the reference to the player specifically passed to me from swfobject in the "object loaded" event. The reference is working, since I'm getting an error back from flash from inside the called method.

Comment: Sorry its not helping , i still think your flash code is fine , the fact that the flash function is called does not neccesarly mean the stream parameter is passed correctly ( it sounds like you are passing null there ) . also because only on ie you get the error it is very likely your error is in the javascript