# How to call dynamically created flash external interface in IE from javascript?

Tags: flash, dom, internet-explorer

What I have:

1. A swf  exports a function via ExternalInterface
2. Javascript creates new embed object and adds it to the document
3. Calling flash functions works fine in other browsers
4. Calling flash functions will fail in **IE 8**

Example of exporting functions in swf:

```
flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback("isActive", ...
```

Example of creating the embed object:

```
var b = document.createElement('embed');

    b.type = 'application\u002fx-shockwave-flash';
    b.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', 'true');
    b.setAttribute('allowNetworking', 'all');
    b.setAttribute('allowScriptAccess', 'always');
    b.width = 500;
    b.height = 400;
    b.src = 'assets\u002fUltra4.UltraApplication\u002fUltra4.UltraApplication+UltraSprite.swf';
```

Example of calling flash external interface in javascript:

```
   try
    {
      e = b.isActive();
    }
    catch (__exc){ }
```

In IE it will catch with message    **"Object doesn't support this property or method"**

How to fix it?

1. Related: http://bojolais.livejournal.com/251383.html
2. Related: [ExternalInterface not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166079/externalinterface-not-working-in-ie)
3. Related: http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/985
4. Related: http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleFixingFlashExternalInterface
5. Related: http://www.dangerouslyawesome.com/2006/10/20/another-swfobject-problem-deproblemed/
6. Related: http://www.airtightinteractive.com/news/?p=71

---

In script debugger I can see a third party script which is supposed to be the bridge:

```
function __flash__arrayToXML(obj) {
    var s = "<array>";
    for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
        s += "<property id=\"" + i + "\">" + __flash__toXML(obj[i]) + "</property>";
    }
    return s+"</array>";
}
function __flash__argumentsToXML(obj,index) {
    var s = "<arguments>";
    for (var i=index; i<obj.length; i++) {
        s += __flash__toXML(obj[i]);
    }
    return s+"</arguments>";
}
function __flash__objectToXML(obj) {
    var s = "<object>";
    for (var prop in obj) {
        s += "<property id=\"" + prop + "\">" + __flash__toXML(obj[prop]) + "</property>";
    }
    return s+"</object>";
}
function __flash__escapeXML(s) {
    return s.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/'/g, "&apos;");
}
function __flash__toXML(value) {
   var type = typeof(value);
    if (type == "string") {
        return "<string>" + __flash__escapeXML(value) + "</string>";
    } else if (type == "undefined") {
        return "<undefined/>";
    } else if (type == "number") {
        return "<number>" + value + "</number>";
    } else if (value == null) {
        return "<null/>";
    } else if (type == "boolean") {
        return value ? "<true/>" : "<false/>";
    } else if (value instanceof Date) {
        return "<date>" + value.getTime() + "</date>";
   } else if (value instanceof Array) {
       return __flash__arrayToXML(value);
   } else if (type == "object") {
       return __flash__objectToXML(value);
   } else {
        return "<null/>"; //???
    }
}
function __flash__addCallback(instance, name) {
  instance[name] = function () { 
    return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));
  }
}
function __flash__removeCallback(instance, name) {
  instance[name] = null;
}
```

Comment: I've used external interface in IE - hard to say anything without seeing the code though.

Comment: The anwser with source example could just create an embed html element via dom functions in javascript and then prove the external interface can be called.

My experience is IE fails to bind the javascript to flash bridge for some reason.

Maybe I should post a bug on microsoft connect? :)

Comment: I have seen in the past that you can end up with a race condition on setting up the external interface, not sure if IE8 makes it worse, the SetCallback function hasn't been called by the time the script interacts with the DOM object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But I think you are missing a couple of things:

1) Your embed tag needs a name attribute. Let's name it "NewFlashMovie" for the subsequent code:

```
b.name = "NewFlashMovie";
```

2) You need to call the "isActive" function differently using an external function. First add this function

```
 function thisMovie(movieName) {
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
     } else {
         return document[movieName];
     }
 }
```

Then you can call the function like this

`thisMovie("NewFlashMovie").isActive();`

From my experience, this "thisMovie" is essential to bridge the IE-Flash calls. This is also documented in the [ExternalInterface documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

3) I also recommend using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) instead of creating your own "embed" object.

Hope these helps.

Comment: for some reason I now got this to work:
x.CallFunction('<invoke name=\"AddShape1\" returntype=\"javascript\"><arguments></arguments></invoke>

Comment: Should this be navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") == -1?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that, for IE, calling Javascript from ActionScript, I've needed to supply an "id" attribute to the **object** tag. The IE way of handling ExternalInterface.call(...) is to call a method on the **object**. IE issues the code

```
document.getElementById("...").SetReturnValue(...)
```

Without an id attribute on your object tag, this reduces to

```
document.getElementById("").SetReturnValue(...)
```

which tries to call SetReturnValue on a null object.

Note that the "id" attribute isn't required for other browsers but doesn't really hurt either.

Something similar may be happening in your case: Perhaps a "name" attribute on the **embed** may help.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be to do with the fact your creating an Embed tag instead of an Object tag? IE traditionally uses Object tags to embed Flash content

See the Adobe tech not for discussion: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html